# Optimize a SQL query to avoid repeating

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization, query-optimization

I have a long sql query that will be executed with 4 different parameters, so I have to repeat this query 4 times. I'm trying to optimize it but it's not working. Here is my query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 Id_Unique FROM Table1 WHERE Parameter= @Parameter1)
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table1 
    SET Value = 'True'
    WHERE Parameter = @Parameter1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table1 (Parameter, Value)
    VALUES(@Parameter1, 'True')
END
```

The only thing that will change with each iteration is the parameter name: `@Parameter1` / `@Parameter2` / `@Parameter3` /`@Parameter4`.
Table1 has only 3 columns `(Id, Parameter, Value)`.

Does anyone know how to optimize this query?

Comment: How can you select Id_Unique from Table1? It isnt there.. Also, you have an index on Parametrr, right?

Comment: @Strawberry I believe SQL Server based on the tag

Comment: Unfortunately, there are some places in SQL where code that is performance-optimized _must_ repeat itself. In this case, your best option is a MERGE statement, which will likely seem repetitive.

Comment: `top 1 ` in `if exists` is redundant and potentially reduce performance.  Use `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE Parameter= @Parameter1)`

Comment: you didn't show us your query

Comment: @AlexKudryashev . . . Can the `top 1` actually reduce performance?  It is redundant but I didn't think it could hurt performance (apart from possibly an extra nanosecond for parsing).

Comment: @Gordon Linoff `top 1` expects some kind of sorting which require resources. In `if exists` condition no data from the query is used so the best practice is as in my previous comment.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev . . . It is recommended to use `TOP` with `ORDER BY`, but it is not necessary for this subquery.  I am not aware the `TOP` can affect the performance, although I do agree that leaving it out is a better practice.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff `top` is totally useless in `if exists` query. Just follow KISS methodology. `top` is applied after `select` is done.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your parameters and their values into a table variable and then perform a single `MERGE` statement, if version of your SQL Server instance supports it (2008 and later).

Such as:

```
-- Incoming set of parameter values
declare @x xml = N'<Parameters>
    <Item Name="Parameter1" Value="Value1" />
    <Item Name="Parameter2" Value="Value2" />
    <Item Name="Parameter3" Value="Value3" />
    <Item Name="Parameter4" Value="Value4" />
</Parameters>';

declare @t table(
    Name varchar(100) primary key,
    Value nvarchar(max) not null
);

insert into @t (Name, Value)
select t.c.value('./@Name', 'varchar(100)') as [Name],
    t.c.value('./@Value', 'nvarchar(max)') as [Value]
from @x.nodes('/Parameters[1]/Item') t(c);

merge dbo.Table1 t
using (select * from @t) s
on t.Parameter = s.Name
when not matched by target then
    insert (Parameter, Value)
    values (s.Name, s.Value)
when matched then
    update set Value = s.Value;
```

Or, you can use any other way to populate the table variable that is most suitable in your situation - that's up to you.